# How to make a video from set of images in android like flipagram

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

I have searched for the solution and found 
- Java CV
- FFmpeg

Need step by step to integrate them like this

Comment: Need Answer For Windows

Comment: have u solve your problem?if yes then please share your ans with me,this is a big issue for me,thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can target latest API (4.1 to 4.3) you should try to play with this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

From changelog:

*Android 4.1 (API level 16) added the MediaCodec class for low-level encoding and decoding of media content. When encoding video, Android 4.1 required that you provide the media with a ByteBuffer array, but Android 4.3 now allows you to use a Surface as the input to an encoder. For instance, this allows you to encode input from an existing video file or using frames generated from OpenGL ES.*

Otherwise, If you want a fully custom solution, you could try the native way and implement your encoder using JNI and **libwebm** (from Google)
http://www.webmproject.org/code/

Comment: What about old versions?

Comment: Could you provide proper example for creating Video from Images, using MediaCodec?