# Programmatically video editing in Android

Tags: android, video

**I have a big problem.** 
I don't know how to edit video on Android.
What I need to do is grab some photos, video and audio from the gallery and somehow merge it together, convert it and save into the gallery.
It Sounds very simple but I don't even know what to use for that. Friend told me Unity for Android could do that. Is there a better way ?
Thank you !

Comment: try one of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662723/how-to-make-a-video-from-set-of-images-in-android-like-flipagram ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643046/how-to-convert-images-into-video-in-android-using-javacv , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900215/android-ffmpeg-create-video-from-sequnce-of-images-using-jni , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Android SDK does not contain any helpful API for what you are intending to do.

You will have to use an external open source library like [FFMPEG](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java) for the rendering/conversion/generation of the video and build your own UI around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try INDE Media for mobile - https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

It has transcoding\remuxing functionality as MediaComposer class and a possibility to join videos and images

[image]